# draw9patch just hangs on Mac 10.7.5

Tags: android

draw9patch just hangs on my Mac 10.7.5. I have reinstalled the android-sdk-macosx.

In the directory android-sdk-macosx/tools I entered ./draw9patch and it is starting up, but then hanging with a white screen?

I have tried to go to the tools/lib directory and run

```
java -jar draw9patch.jar
```

with the same result.

Java:

```
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-456, mixed mode)
```

Dump:

https://gist.github.com/powder366/5973285

https://gist.github.com/powder366/5973275

https://gist.github.com/powder366/5973228

Have anyone seen this? Suggestion on how to find the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on 10.8.4. Running jar from Enrichman produces the same result. I am on:
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-456, mixed mode)

Comment: Ok - just installed Sun's JDK and draw9patch works. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update with this Java patch http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 also see here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57473&can=1&q=draw9patch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: I know the feeling:-)

Answer (score 0):

From the script I can see this comment:

```
# need to use "java.ext.dirs" because "-jar" causes classpath to be ignored
# might need more memory, e.g. -Xmx128M
```

but anyway both command work for me:

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=. -jar draw9patch.jar
java -jar draw9patch.jar
```

Probably you have a failing jar. Can you try with [mine](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/492024/draw9patch.jar)?

[I'm on a Mac running Mountain Lion 10.8.4 but I had no problem with Lion 10.7.5]