# Android 9 patch won't load

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a question regarding Android 9 patch. Basically when I click and open the 9Patch tool, the screen went blank and can never start. I have tried to drag a picture into it, and it just crashes. Things I have tried are:

1. re-download Android SDK and re-install
2. re-start my computer

I am sure I have downloaded the correct version of Android SDK, so my guess is maybe it has nothing to do with Android, but settings in my computer, but I don't know where and how to fix it. So any suggestions and advices are welcome!! Thanks![image: 9 patch blank]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem on Mac.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57473&can=1&q=draw9patch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

There seems to be a patch available from Apple which should fix this problem.

Also, check this thread.

[draw9patch just hangs on Mac 10.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567188/draw9patch-just-hangs-on-mac-10-7-5)

Comment: Hi Kumar,Thanks for your answer, it is working now. So I followed the second link and downloaded "Java for OS X 2013-004" from  [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use Android Asset Studio**

This [link](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) presents Icon generators and Simple nine-patch generator. it's very simple.